# Retrieving sql data in array

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make very simple class, where I can retrieve data from table.

```
class dbCore{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $serverAddress;
private function createConnection(){
    return mysql_connect($this->serverAddress, $this->username, $this->password);
}

public function __construct($db=array()){
    $this->username = $db['username'];
    $this->password = $db['password'];
    $this->database = $db['database'];
    $this->serverAddress = $db['serverAddress'];
}

public function checkConnection(){
    $connection = $this->createConnection();
    if( $connection )
        mysql_close($connection);
    return !!$connection;
}

public function getAll($tableName){
    $data=array();
    $connection = $this->createConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableName;
    if ($connection){
        mysql_select_db($this->database);
        $result=mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            array_push($data,$row);
        }
        return $data;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

when I call `$db->getAll('mytable');` it retrieves:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Riga
            [2] => Liepaja
            [3] => 2014-11-20
            [4] => 2014-11-08
            [5] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Riga
            [2] => Liepaja
            [3] => 2014-11-19
            [4] => 2014-11-09
            [5] => 3
        )

)
```

But I want it to be `id => 1, city => Riga` etc. But I dont want to write it myself. I want it to take it from column names and put in key values. Is there easy way to do it? I could retrieve all field names and replace them, but it seems not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you still using mysql_? It's deprecated.

Anyway, use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`

Comment: It was first I found online. What should I use then?

Comment: Use mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php